# cannot pass String cookieHeader to setRequestProperty()

Tags: java

This line `conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie",cookieHeader);` wont reed `cookieHeader` if i manualy pass in the string like this `conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "ci_session=5dsjqh39nkj7nm98nokrukoesr6iir67");` then it works fine, anny idea why this dos not work?

```
    package javaapplication5;

    import java.io.*;
    import java.net.*;
    import java.util.*;

    public class JavaApplication5 {

         public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            String urlString = "http://example.se/";
            String params ="";
            int timeout =1000;

           String cookieHeader = getcookieHeader(urlString,params);

           System.out.println(post(urlString,params,cookieHeader,timeout));

        } 

     public static String getcookieHeader(String urlString, String params) throws MalformedURLException, IOException{      

    // your first request that does the authentication
    URL authUrl = new URL(urlString);
    HttpURLConnection authCon = (HttpURLConnection) authUrl.openConnection();
    authCon.connect();

    // temporary to build request cookie header
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    // find the cookies in the response header from the first request
    List<String> cookies = authCon.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie");
    if (cookies != null) {
        for (String cookie : cookies) {
            if (sb.length() > 0) {
                sb.append("; ");
            }

            // only want the first part of the cookie header that has the value
            String value = cookie.split(";")[0];
            sb.append(value);
        }
    }

        // build request cookie header to send on all subsequent requests
        String cookieHeader = sb.toString(); 

      return cookieHeader;
     } 

        public static String post(String urlString, String params, String cookieHeader, int timeout) throws Exception {

       String response = null;

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");



            conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookieHeader);// does not work 
//conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "ci_session=5dsjqh39nkj7nm98nokrukoesr6iir67"); works fine.. 


            System.out.println(cookieHeader);// prints out "ci_session=5dsjqh39nkj7nm98nokrukoesr6iir67"


            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            conn.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(params.getBytes().length));
            conn.connect();

            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(params);
            dos.flush();

            is = conn.getInputStream();
            Scanner s = new Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
            response = s.hasNext() ? s.next() : null;
        } finally {
            if (dos != null) {
                dos.close();
            }

            if (is != null) {
                is.close();
            }

            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }

        return response;
    }

    }
```

Comment: Can you explain in detail what works and what does not, respectively what is your error message (http status code, exception, ...).

Comment: System.out.println(cookieHeader);// prints out "ci_session=5dsjqh39nkj7nm98nokrukoesr6iir67" then i set  "cookieHeader" to the 
 conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookieHeader);and it does not work.. if i pass the resault from  System.out.println(cookieHeader); witch is "ci_session=5dsjqh39nkj7nm98nokrukoesr6iir67"  like this 
//conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "ci_session=5dsjqh39nkj7nm98nokrukoesr6iir67"); then script works fine..  i cannot figure outh why cookieHeader wont work like this: 
 conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookieHeader);

Comment: But how dou you determine the result "it does not work". Do you get an error code from your server/url?  Do you record your `HTTP Post` and observe that the `Cookie` header is not set? In other words, how does your response differ in your two cases?

Comment: the code is used to connect to website and login, it works i fine without errors,  the only difference is that it shows logdin and did not login in the response data..

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.. Just added this line: `CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());`  to `getcookieHeader()` under `authCon.connect()`; and removed

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookieHeader);
```

With `CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());` HttpURLConnection will automatically save any cookies it receives and send them back with the next request to the same host.